# Вывод нескольких значений из одного поля БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

Работаю с компонентом в Joomla. Есть поле `programs_id` в базе данных, в котором хранится несколько значений через запятую. К примеру, идентификаторы(1,2,3,4,5). Возможно ли вывести эти значения по отдельности в массив? Я понимаю что это противоречит первой нормальной форме, но структура БД досталась мне в таком виде.

```
$query ="SELECT `name` FROM #__bh_program_programtypes WHERE`id`='".$this->item->program_id."'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$desc=$db->loadRow();
echo $desc[0]; ?>
```

Получаю запрос такого вида:

```
SELECT `name` FROM #__bh_program_programtypes WHERE`id`='1,2,3,4,13,14'
```

Однако логично что на выводе получаю только одно значение, из шести, так как вывод не цикле

Comment: запрос вроде бы должен иметь такой вид: `SELECT name FROM #__bh_program_programtypes WHERE id  IN(1,2,3,4,13,14)` И да, надо использовать цикл

Comment: Эдуард В таком виде он тоже был, и результат вывода совершенно идентичен описанному мною. А как в таком случае достать по отдельности значения в массив?

Comment: вот это `$desc=$db->loadRow();` прописать в скобках цикла while() а в теле цикла прописать что то вроде `echo $desc['name'];`

Comment: Эдуард, неа, не выводит. Он должен сначала все значения в массив положить, а потом уже выводить. А loadRow только по строкам выводит, но не одному полю

Comment: если в переменной $this->item->program_id у вас массив вида 1,2,3,4 то попробуйте **[вот так](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d395d455777486ca174569e0f8262fe3bdba950b)**

Comment: а если в переменной $this->item->program_id строка - тогда **[вот так](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfc035c2aa94c9794dab250d3c864dd8dbef7fa0)** Теоретически один из этих вариантов должен отработать.

Comment: а что бы в массив сохранить значения, замените в теле цикла конструкцию echo $desc['name'] . '<br />'; на $arr[] = $desc['name']; И не забудьте перед циклом объявить этот массив $arr = []; чтобы не было нотиса.

Comment: Эдуард, спасибо за помощь) Буду пробывать. Айда что нибудь выйдет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69097/discussion-between--and-flap-jack).

Answer (score 0):

```
$query ="SELECT `name` FROM #__bh_program_programtypes WHERE`id` IN (".$this->item->program_id.")";
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но у меня все равно выводится одно значение.

Comment: Тогда мне кажется, что Вы где-то даёте неверные сведения о значениях и структурах. На что наводят в т.ч. и мысли о явных опечатках (напр. *Есть поле program**s**_id в базе данных*, но *$this->item->program_id*)...

Comment: Сейчас поправлю описание, чтобы было проще понять